# Using Intent with actions

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, action

Right. I have an action that needs to call another activity. As I understand this, I need to use Intents to do so if I want to parse values to this activity.

However, my code fails and im a little lost as to why.

My main activity:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ArrayList<menuItem> AMI = new ArrayList<menuItem>();
    /*Menu item: String name, String menu ID*/
    /*ToDo: Logic to fecth new menu structure from server*/
    menuItem MI1 = new menuItem("menu item 1","1");
    menuItem MI2 = new menuItem("menu item 2","2");
    AMI.add(MI1);
    AMI.add(MI2);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView01);
    gridview.setAdapter(new menuAdapter(this, AMI));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
            //Toast.makeText(Runner.this, AMI.get(position).getMenuID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), showMenu.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("parentID", AMI.get(position).getMenuID());
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });
```

The "Toast" works just fine, however when I call the showMenu class it crashes.
The showMenu class looks as follows:

```
public class showMenu extends Activity{
public String menuParent = "";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.submenu);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null)
    {
        menuParent = extras.getString("parentID");
    }
    /*ToDo: Logic to fecth new menu structure from server*/
    final ArrayList<menuItem> AMI = new ArrayList<menuItem>();
    menuItem MI1 = new menuItem("submenu 1","1");
    menuItem MI2 = new menuItem("submenu 2","2");
    AMI.add(MI1);
    AMI.add(MI2);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView01);
    gridview.setAdapter(new subMenuAdapter(this, AMI));
}

    public class subMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<menuItem> MIL = new ArrayList<menuItem>();
        public static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 10;
        public subMenuAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<menuItem> AMI) {
            MIL = AMI;
        }
        public int getCount() {
            return MIL.size();

        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                v = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
                TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
                tv.setText(MIL.get(position).getMenuname());

            } else {
                v = convertView;
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```

}

Any idea why it crashes?

Comment: You really have to get your LogCat output working. It will show you why your application is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to register your Intent in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="Package.Name.showMenu"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"></activity>
```

Comment: Doh!.. Yes you are right. The error was "ActivityNotFound", could have said to my self I had forgotten to register it. Ohh well, at least i have read up on the Intent class now.

Answer (score 0):

As both activities are from same application, there are some other ways as well to pass data between instead of intents. check the link below:

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3

If you want to use only intents, can you please specify the error you are facing, so that someone can reply you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to parse values to another activity,you must use startActivityForResult.This is called sub_activity.